# How to print in Python from a object with out showing the dtype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to print values from inside a variable in python.

The variable is having first row of a Dataframe saved into it.

I want to print column1, column2 from it, But when I print I get column1 value along with dtype, columnname as seen in the screenshot.

How do I just print the value.
Ex: uptown, 929 w. .......

[image: P]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
print(result.name.values)
```